# Spring security not working when adding a second url-intercept

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

SS been working well, until I added a second url intercept, as below:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" /> <!-- new one-->
<security:intercept-url pattern="/*.htm" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

username and password work ok, and I walked through the debuger in provider manger class and saw that user is being retrieved correctly from the database, and so on, but not sure why access is denied when roles are identical to the other url pattern. both of them dont work now, when i remove the first pattern, *.htm starts to work again, very confusing.

```
12 Dec 2012 09:28:16 - DEBUG - org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/index.jsp'; against '/index*'
12 Dec 2012 09:28:16 - DEBUG - org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /index.jsp; Attributes: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]
12 Dec 2012 09:28:16 - DEBUG - org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
12 Dec 2012 09:28:16 - DEBUG - org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@8ca9a2d, returned: -1
12 Dec 2012 09:28:16 - DEBUG - org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@2d5004dd, returned: 0
12 Dec 2012 09:28:16 - DEBUG - org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.security.access.event.AuthorizationFailureEvent[source=FilterInvocation: URL: /index.jsp]
12 Dec 2012 09:28:16 - DEBUG - org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:845)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**EDIT**
What's not working now is that spring-security isnot redirecting to the accessed page after authenticating, in this case to `index.jsp`.

**EDIT**
Spring Security config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
    <security:http auto-config="true" create-session="never">
        <!-- security:intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" /-->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*.htm" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout.htm" logout-success-url="/" />
    </security:http>

    <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <property name="providers">
            <list>
                <ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
            <security:password-encoder hash="md5" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>


</beans>
```

Comment: This isn't an error. Check the FAQ - it's a debug message which is normal for an unauthenticated user and you'll see it in any application. You'll need to be a bit more specific about what isn't working.

Comment: Sorry, but you'll need to provide more information. Please post your Spring Security configuration and replace the stacktrace with the relevant debug log (for the user authentication).

Comment: i figured it out man, the log-out-success url was pointing to index.jsp, so it was doing a full log-in --> log out cycle in place, i changed the success url to another page that's not secured and it works now

Comment: thanks for asking me to put in the config file, i spotted it when i was pasting it into the site

Comment: Post your answer as the solution and accept it to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what I wrote in the comments above, the root cause of the problem was having the `create-session` attribute set to `never` on `security:http` bean. `Spring` was forcing the application to use the anonymous user after it fails to create the session. I removed the attribute, and it is happy again.